# Python - Requests HTTP Library SSL Key

Tags: python, http, ssl, https, python-requests

I am using requests library to complete communication with https websites. This works great, my only problem is that wireshark no longer captures plain text information in the "Decrypted SSL Data" tab as it does after following this instructional :

https://jimshaver.net/2015/02/11/decrypting-tls-browser-traffic-with-wireshark-the-easy-way/

Setup enviromental variable that allows chrome and firefox to store ssl keys in file, wireshark uses this file in real time.

Is their a way I can modify a simple https request script such as this :

```
import requests
resp = requests.get("https://www.google.com", allow_redirects=True)
```

to also store the ssl key into file as chrome and firefox do?

From what I understand about OpenSSL implementations that would do similar, you'd have to find the master secret and session key in memory - is this doable when running from cmd or practical?

Comment: please check selenium library

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be possible now with Requests.

I have set `SSLKEYLOGFILE=secrets.log` and then ran a request via requests.get() and `secrets.log` is now populated with TLS secrets. I am using requests v2.25.1 and urllib3 v1.26.3.

Apparently, it took a while for OpenSSL to provide APIs necessary to extract keying information, and then time for bindings to be created in pyOpenSSL to utilize those APIs and then for that to bubble up to urllib3.

See this issue for more details: https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/3674

Comment: Thank you, that looks like really useful information!

Comment: Works with python 3.9 and requests 2.26.0, thank you :)

Comment: Where do you set SSLKEYLOGFILE=secrets.log ? My code is                              
  ```import requests

url = 'https://www.w3schools.com/python/demopage.php'
myobj = {'somekey': 'somevalue'}

x = requests.post(url, json = myobj)

print(x.text)```

Comment: You can set it in your system's environment variables like (on Linux) `export SSLKEYLOGFILE=secrets.log` prior to executing the script or you can probably set it within Python like `import os; os.environ["SSLKEYLOGFILE"] = "secrets.log"` prior to making the request. @GeorgeOfTheRF

Answer (score -3):

`openssl s_client -connect www.google.com:443 -showcerts`

you will see all certs that google site uses.

Comment: Looking for private session key, not public certs.